Python Flask Pattern Generation: First Row Misalignment Issue
I'm working on a Python Flask web application that generates various patterns based on user input. I'm specifically trying to create a star pattern, but the first row is consistently misaligned. The pattern is generated correctly, except for the first row, which appears to be indented or shifted to the right.
note: this is my first time using Flask
code(pythonWork.html):
<body class="no-animation">
    <div class="pyWork">
      <h1>My Python Work</h1>
      <br />

      <dl>
        <dt><h2>Patterns:</h2></dt>
        <dd>
          <form action="/generatePattern" method="POST">
            <label for="pattern">Select a pattern type:</label>
            <select name="pattern" id="pattern">
              <option value="star">Star Pattern</option>
              <option value="number">Number Pattern</option>
              <option value="triangle">Triangle Pattern</option>
            </select>
            <br /><br />
            <label for="rows">Enter number of rows:</label>
            <input type="number" id="rows" name="rows" min="1" required />
            <br /><br />
            <button type="submit" class="button1">Generate</button>
          </form>
        </dd>
        <dd>
          <pre>
            {% if pattern %}
            {{ pattern }}
            {% endif %}
            </pre
          >
        </dd>
      </dl>
      <a href="/" class="link1">Back to Home</a>
    </div>
  </body>

here is css code:
.pyWork {
  color: rgb(152, 151, 151);
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: auto;
  height: fit-content;
}

pre {
  background-color: #23232e;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: monospace;
  text-indent: 0;
}

.button1 {
  width: auto;
  color: white;
  background-color: #4285f4;
  border: none;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.button1:hover {
  background-color: #357ae8;
}


and here is app.py code:
@app.route('/PyWork')
def python_work():
    return render_template('pythonWork.html')

@app.route('/generatePattern', methods=['POST'])
def generate_pattern():
    pattern_type = request.form['pattern']
    rows = int(request.form['rows'])
    if pattern_type == 'star':
        pattern = generateStar(rows)
    elif pattern_type == 'number':
        pattern = generateNumber(rows)
    elif pattern_type == 'triangle':
        pattern = generateTriangle(rows)
    else:
        pattern = "Invalid selection!"
    return render_template('pythonWork.html', pattern=pattern)

# Pattern generation functions
def generateStar(n):
    return '\n'.join('*' * i for i in range(1, n + 1))

def generateNumber(n):
    return '\n'.join(' '.join(str(j) for j in range(1, i + 1)) for i in range(1, n + 1))

def generateTriangle(n):
    return '\n'.join(' ' * (n - i) + '*' * (2 * i - 1) for i in range(1, n + 1))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)


expected result:
*
**


Actual result:
as you can see the first row is aligned to the right.
I've tried the following approaches to resolve the misalignment:
CSS text-indent: I've ensured that the text-indent property for the pre element is set to 0 in my CSS stylesheet.
Hidden characters: I've carefully inspected the generated pattern for any hidden or non-printable characters that might be causing the alignment issue.
messed with pre function in css
Despite these efforts, the first row remains misaligned.

Solved it. in the pythonWork.html:
the pre tag was adding extra white space. change it to this:
      <pre>
        {%- if pattern -%}
            {{ pattern }}
        {%- endif -%}
    </pre
      >

